# MySQL 5.7 JSON компоновка двух массивов

Tags: mysql, json

Есть 2 "массива". В JSON MySQL 5.7.

Первый из них представляет собой набор ответов пользователя на вопросы теста
вида <номер_вопроса> {<номера_ответов>}, ...

Второй - список ключей по 6 шкалам.

1) Ответы пользователя на вопросы теста:

```
{
"answers" : {
    "1" : [
        "2"
    ],
    "10" : [
        "1"
    ],
    "11" : [
        "1"
    ],
    "12" : [
        "2"
    ],
    "13" : [
        "1"
    ],
    "14" : [
        "1"
    ],
    "15" : [
        "1"
    ],
    "16" : [
        "1"
    ],
    "17" : [
        "1"
    ],
    "18" : [
        "1"
    ],
    "19" : [
        "1"
    ],
    "2" : [
        "3"
    ],
    "20" : [
        "1"
    ],
    "21" : [
        "1"
    ],
    "22" : [
        "1"
    ],
    "23" : [
        "3"
    ],
    "24" : [
        "1"
    ],
    "3" : [
        "2"
    ],
    "4" : [
        "1"
    ],
    "5" : [
        "1"
    ],
    "6" : [
        "1"
    ],
    "7" : [
        "1"
    ],
    "8" : [
        "3"
    ],
    "9" : [
        "1"
    ]
},
"test" : "profexposure"
```

}

2) Ключи, собранные в Шкалы. Упрощ. формат <имя_шкалы> {<номер_вопроса>: {<номера_ответов>}}

```
"counting" : {
    "scales" : {
        "Общительность" : {
            "answers" : {
                "1" : 1,
                "11" : 1,
                "14" : 1,
                "16" : 1,
                "19" : 1,
                "21" : 1,
                "23" : 1,
                "25" : 1,
                "27" : 1,
                "29" : 1,
                "3" : 1,
                "32" : 1,
                "34" : 1,
                "37" : 1,
                "39" : 1,
                "5" : 1,
                "8" : 1
            }
        },
        "Стабильность" : {
            "answers" : {
                "10" : 1,
                "13" : 1,
                "15" : 1,
                "17" : 1,
                "2" : 1,
                "20" : 1,
                "22" : 1,
                "26" : 1,
                "28" : 1,
                "31" : 1,
                "33" : 1,
                "35" : 1,
                "38" : 1,
                "4" : 1,
                "40" : 1,
                "7" : 1,
                "9" : 1
            }
        },
        "Шкала лжи" : {
            "answers" : {
                "12" : 2,
                "18" : 2,
                "24" : 2,
                "30" : 2,
                "36" : 2,
                "6" : 2
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Как собственно мне подсчитать сколько баллов для каждой шкалы набрано?

P.S. Делал ранее подобное без JSON в MySQL, но сейчас использую JSON MySQL 5.7, т.к. с ним информацию типа "тесты психологические" (под несколько десятков тестов с различными правилами подсчета), удобнее хранить в JSON, читабельнее, проще и т.п.